# Spark Standalone acts differently with python and scala

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am exploring Spark and found an inconsistency with Spark Standalone (SS for short). Here some clue about my cluster:

- d125.dtvhadooptest -> Best datanode
- d124.dtvhadooptest
- d211.dtvhadooptest -> Worst datanode

I am running exactly same job via python and scala. SS is sharing tasks among executor processes near equally when job is submitted as python script. However when job is submitted as scala script, SS shares tasks  heterogeneously. Screenshots will explain it better I guess:

**Python:**
[image: PySpark]

**Scala:**
[image: spark-shell]

With scala, job is running significantly faster (about 55 minutes.). When using python job is done in about 90 minutes. And I think the reason for this outcome is task sharing among executors.

My question is, why SS behaves differently with scala and python? And how I can make SS behave when I use python as it behaves when I use scala?

Comment: I don't know why it distributes the tasks differently, but as for the time difference, scala will always perform better than python since Spark is written in scala.

Comment: I see your point, but I think making cluster manager (Spark Standalone in my case) do similar task distribution can reduce performance difference between python and scala.

Answer (score 1):

Task scheduling is exactly the same whether you use Python or Scala. The difference in performance is due to Python having to pickle and unpickle everything over a socket to a separate Python process that runs the Python code.

Given the above I think it's a waste of time trying to figure out why the task numbers are distributed one way or another. It may be explained by queuing theory (the different task time distributions lead to different task count distributions). If you want to figure it out, I recommend upgrading to Spark 1.4.0 which offers more detail about the task scheduling timeline. (Spark 1.2.1 is pretty old at this point.)